# Custom expandable and swipeable UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, custom-cell

I created a custom UITableViewCell that can be expandable when user click on it. And also user can swipe to delete the row. But when user swipe,cell height changed and over written on the bottom cell.
[image: At normal case. When user didn't swiper or click on the cell]

[image: When user swiped. Cell over written on the bottom cell]

[image: When user clicked on the cell]

Code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete") { (action, index) in

        self.deleteIndexPath = indexPath

        self.deleteKey(self.keys[(self.deleteIndexPath?.row)!])
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([self.deleteIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)

        self.tableView.reloadData()



    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.swipedIndexPath = indexPath
    return [delete]

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let index = indexPath

    if selectedIndexPath != nil{
        if index == selectedIndexPath{
            return 143


        }else{
            return 71
        }



    }else{
        return 71

    }


}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic )





    switch selectedIndexPath {
    case nil:
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    default:
        if selectedIndexPath! == indexPath{
            selectedIndexPath = nil
        }else{
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
            }
        }


    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)



}
```

Note: Two cells in the picture has the same name and information.

Comment: Have you tried with constraints?? Try to use constraint for cell height and change it on cell click.

Comment: No I didn't try it. I set it's constraints,but I did't change it on cell click. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Initially set cell height constraint constant to your min value and when you click on cell set that constant value to your new cell height.

Comment: When I swipe the cell, cell get to be deformed.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of a code? Thanks